# Can't migrate to Gradle DSL plugin, 'com.android.library'] was not found

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-library

I was trying to move from Gradle's legacy way to apply plugin to the new DSL one in my Android . But I'm having some issues:

My only build.gradle looks similar to this:

```
ext {
  androidxVersion = "1.0.0"
  lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
}

def properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())


buildscript {
  def kotlin_version = XXXX

  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to have something like this:

```
buildscript {
  def kotlin_version = XXXX
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

plugins{
  id 'com.android.library'
  id 'kotlin-android'
}

ext {
  androidxVersion = "1.0.0"
  lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Plugin [id: 'com.android.library'] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

And if I try to put the plugin block first, I'm getting the error:

```
all buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks in the script
```